# Mura 6.1 Include cfm page error

Tags: coldfusion, railo, mura

I am using this code for display my page in page content in MURA 6.1

```
<div>[mura]$.dspInclude('display_objects/custom/main.cfm')[/mura]</div>
```

But it gives me the error below:

> Note: If you wish to use an absolute template path (for example,
>   template="/mypath/index.cfm") with CFINCLUDE, you must create a
>   mapping for the path using the ColdFusion Administrator. Or, you can
>   use per-application settings to specify mappings specific to this
>   application by specifying a mappings struct to THIS.mappings in
>   Application.cfc. 
>  Using relative paths (for example,
>   template="index.cfm" or template="../index.cfm") does not require the
>   creation of any special mappings. It is therefore recommended that you
>   use relative paths with CFINCLUDE whenever possible. Could not find
>   the included template
>   /muraWRM/default/includes/display_objects/custom/main.cfm.

The physical path is

```
[siteid]/default\includes\themes\rescue\display_objects
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<div>[mura]$.dspInclude('themes/rescue/display_objects/custom/main.cfm')[/mura]</div>
```

Your include is being called from the includes folder, so you need to include the themes folder and the rescue folder to get to the right path.

For consistency across themes, you might want to use Mura's setting for the theme name, but I would have to look that up.
If you are ok hard coding it, this should work just fine.

Comment: Steve Answer is Hi Tariq,


If you're including a file in your theme, you simply need to use $.dspThemeInclude('path/to/your/file/under/your/theme.cfm')

-Steve